# Erro HTTP 404.17 - Not Found para um WCF em Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis, wcf

Oi, eu já tentei a maioria das coisas na web para a resolução desse problema, mas continuo recebendo erro "Erro HTTP 404.17 - Not Found".

Já rodei `servicemodelreg -i` já rodei `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` já coloquei permissões na pasta, já coloquei acesso para qualquer pessoa no serviço, já retirei módulos do IIS que bloqueavam svc, já coloquei para acesso anônimo, já fui na parte de habilitar serviços e habilitei tudo do IIS, e mesmo com o framework 4.5 instalado eu só consegui (só tinha a opção) de habilitar o framework 3.5 do WCF, mas eu fiz....

enfim, já tentei muita coisa e continua dando esse erro em um serviço registrado no IIS.

É um Windows Server 2008.

O que mais posso fazer? Estou há uns 4 dias com esse problema (normalmente eu paro e vou programar outra coisa e volto nesse problema quando a cabeça esfria) mas nada.

Podem me ajudar?

**--------------------
EDIT:**

Já tentei fazer um WCF em 3.5 e também não rodou no servidor.

Eu instalei o 4.5.2 vindo desse link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42643

Comment: Tente adicionar isso no seu web.config: <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
 </system.webServer>

Comment: Outra coisa: o Windows Server 2008 não roda o framework 4.5

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira já tinha <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />  no meu web config

Comment: Vc rodou `servicemodelreg -i` de dentro da pasta do 3.5?

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira mas eu instalei o 4.5.2 daqui: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42643
e tenho sites feitos em 4.5 que rodam no mesmo servidor. Ou vc quer dizer que somente o WCF 4.5 não roda? E eu fiz um teste: criai um serviço 3.5 e deu erro também no mesmo servidor

Comment: falha minha, desculpe. Bem, só me sobra o palpite do servicemodelreg, mesmo :/

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira eu rodei esse comando na pasta do 4.0, na do 3.5 deu erro de comando não existente

Comment: nesse caso vc roda na pasta do 2.0 ou 3.0 (não lembro qual dos dois é a base version)

Comment: Priscila, você já deu uma olhada neste link? http://gasparnagy.com/2014/01/enable-net-4-0-wcf-hosing-in-iis-8/

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio eu tentei, mas não chega na 4ª imagem... o_o tem algo muito errado com esse servidor e estou pensando em abandonar ele :/